# Excel Power Query - checking date in a list of dates using M

Tags: excel, powerquery, mashup

I have to compare if a date in table A is present in all of the dates column in table B, return 1 if yes and no otherwise. I am using Excel Power Query and my formula is this:

Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "BL_Count", each if List.Contains(Dates[Dates_WeekStart],[BL_WeekStart]) then 1 else 0)

I get all as 0s though. What am I doing wrong?

Dates table has all weekStart dates from 2015 onwards. There is no other column in that table. 
BL_WeekStart has various WeekStart values, I need to compare if that date is present in Dates and return a 1.

Comment: You can merge both tables. Expand and them check the result in a conditional column

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. Check types of Dates_WeekStart and BL_WeekStart columns - they should be the same. If the column has type date and another one - datetime then you always will get zeros.